# Create table with some column's type defined as some function's returning type

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The following SQL statement will create a table `t`, with a column `c1`, whose type is defined as `bigint(21) unsigned`, which is the returning type of function `INET_ATON`:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') AS c1;
```

But the statement also inserts a row. I wonder if there is a way to create the table and make its columns' type defined as some function's returning type, without inserting a row.

I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t LIKE SELECT INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') AS c1;
```

But this doesn't match the SQL syntax.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

PS: Any standard SQL statement is OK, the MariaDB or MySQL supported statement is also OK.

Comment: Can you enlighten me as t how this would be a useful thing to do.

Comment: @P.Salmon This is just a demo, not useful on its own. But there are realistic situations where people want to set some function's return type as a column's type, because by design, the column's values only can be set as the function's returning value. Using a statement without explicitly declaring the type avoids coupled hard-code.

Comment: Are you sure it's the return (data)type and not what mysql guesses based on what is returned?

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry, what do you mean by guess? The nested selected clause is executed, the returning type is actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use where clause to create a condition which will never be true like below:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') AS c1 where 1=2;
```

This will create the table without adding any rows into it.

Comment: Good point! Thanks! But I am still wondering if there's a _dedicated_ syntax to achieve this. If there's no other answers that provide a dedicated syntax. I am going to pick this one.

Comment: Actually I didn't use this before. While reading your question the idea just strikes. And it's working. Thanks a lot for the question. Let's try to find something better from google.